# Uploading certificate / key to AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I've been given a zip file with two .crt files and asked to replace a certificate on an AWS elastic load balancer.  The files are:

randomNumbers.crt

```
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
lots of numbers and letters
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and gd_bundle.crt

```
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
lots of numbers and letters
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
lots of numbers and letters
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
lots of numbers and letters
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Amazon IAM wants three files during upload:
Private key, public key certificate, and certificate chain (optional)

I'm fairly certain my second file is the certificate chain, but I'm not sure what the other file is, and if I'm simply missing one of the required files.

I ran randomNumbers.crt through

```
 openssl x509 -in randomNumbers.crt -text -noout
```

Which spit out a bunch of information about the certificate... leading me to believe that is a certificate.  Am I just missing a private key?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have the certificate chain and domain certificate but not the private key. To verify check single set of 'lots of numbers and letters' common in both files. Example PEM-encoded, unencrypted private key looks follows.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Base64-encoded private key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html) documentation for more details on key formats.